# Walmart electrode.io for react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, server-side-rendering, walmart-electrode

Has anyone evaluated the electrode.io framework for implementing React, Redux, ReactRouter? What are the pros and cons of this framework? Is it worth considering or best to create your own React/Redux stack? Thanks